# Pass PHP variable to JavaScript with Callback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to validate a password via `JavaScript` with help of an `Ajax` function.

If it is successful, I want to pass back the variable (boolean, true or false) and do something in my `PHP` file depending on the callback.

But this doesn't work. Here is my code:

**PHP file: update.php**

```
<input href="javascript:void(0);" role="button" ype="submit" value="Submit" onclick="ValidatePassword()>'
```

**JAVASCRIPT: ValidatePassword()**

In my `Javascript` function I check the password with this `ajax` call and if it is successfull, it should callback the result to the php function.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "checkpw.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response)
    {
        if (result != -1 )
        {
            $("#passwd").val('');

            // RETURN TO PHP FILE update.php -> PW IS VALID
        } else {
            // RETURN TO PHP FILE update.php -> PW IS INVALID
        }
    }
});
```

**PHP file: update.php**

Now I want to use the callback in the `php` function like:

```
<?php

if (passwordCallback == true)
...
else
...

?>
```

What should I do in the `ajax` success function to return the value to my `php` file?

Comment: you can use json_enode or simply echo 'success' of 'fail' in update.php, use response to get the value

Comment: Also, please notice that the parameter in `success: function` is `response` while in your condition you're using `result`.

Comment: @Devs: Can you explain how to use json or echo in this case?

Comment: success: function(response)
    {
        if (result != -1 ) why are you checking "result"when you have "response" variable?

Comment: Don't do this. Anyone can call your `update.php` and pretend the password is valid if you go via JavaScript. You should instead call `update.php` via `checkpw.php` and send the response directly from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments, if this is not coded correctly it can lead to security issues. If it is coded correctly then it will end up doing the password check twice when it only needs to be done once.

Instead what you could do is:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "checkandupdate.php", //Combination of both
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response)
    {
        if (result != -1 ) {
            $("#passwd").val('');    
        }
    }
});
```

**File checkandupdate.php**

```
<?php
require "checkpw.php"; // Or whatever you need to do to validate the password
// At this point "checkpw.php" determined if the password is valid and(ideally) you can check the outcome
//Assume we store the outcome of the check in $passwordIsValid as a boolean indicating success
if ($passwordIsValid) {
    //Do whatever you need to do when the password is valid
    echo "1"
}
else {
   // Do whatever you need to do when the password is invalid
   echo "-1";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a JavaScript function like:

```js
function sendReturnToPHP(url, result) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: JSON.parse(result),
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {}
  });
}
```

Now you can easily call it in your request success.